# Phonegap 3.0 - 3.4 does not auto build in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cordova, compiler-construction, build

I have followed the steps and setup latest phonegap 3.4 in Eclipse.

Whenever i need to build the project, I have to open CLI and run "phonegap build android". Then i click on the run in Eclipse to run the project in my emu.

I have used the previous Phonegap 2.9. The builder executes together when I click on the run button in Eclipse.

Anyway to automate the builder in Eclipse for Phonegap 3.4 ? Under the Eclipse project, there is a section call "Builders", possible to add it in?

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to run it manually using cordova command in your command prompt/terminal.

Comment: Under the Eclipse project, there is a section call "Builders", possible to add it in?

Comment: which one? i'm not following. details?